# Як перекласти "nondimensionalization"

Tags: переклад, from-english, одним-словом, суфікси

Як перекласти *[nondimensionalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondimensionalization)*? В цьому контексті *dimension* перекладають як *розмірність*, бо йдеться про одиниці розмірності маси, часу, довжини тощо.

*Знерозмірнення*? Як взагалі можна перекладати суфікс *-ization* окрім як *-ізація*.

Comment: Обов'язково одним словом? Може "зниження розмірності"?

Comment: @Artemix дякую, це хороший варіант, та хотілось би одним словом.

Answer (score 1):

Вікіпедія стверджує, що є таке поняття як "обезрозмірення",

> Для чисельного розв'язування фізичних задач, фізичне рівняння потрібно спочатку *обезрозмірити*, тобто ввести нові безрозмірні змінні. Такі змінні зазвичай одержують, ділячи певну фізичну величину на її характерне значення.

див. статтю [Рівняння#Особливості рівнянь фізики](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F#%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96_%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D1%84%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8), що англійською і буде перекладатися як "nondimensionalization" (згідно до визначення з англійської [Вікіпедії](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondimensionalization), це процес часткової або повної заміни одиниць рівняння, яке містить фізичні величини, більш підхожими змінними).

Ось деякі приклади текстів, де вживання цього слова: [1](http://www.iapmm.lviv.ua/dissertation/dis_Turchyn.pdf) і [2](http://www.iapmm.lviv.ua/chyt2016/theses/Rakocha.pdf)). Цитати з текстів: "...розміщення шарів з урахуванням обезрозмірення більш ніж удвічі пере- вищує аналогічні значення..." та "обезрозмірення математичної моделі". Також ви можете зустріти вживання цього терміну на Вікіпедії у статті про [Комірки Бенара](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0) ("Після обезрозмірювання змінна z змінюється від 0 до 1").

Однак слід зауважити, що даного слова немає у СУМі.

Comment: чому ми кажемо *знезараження*, а не *обеззараження*? Я не певен щодо цього префіксу.

Answer (score 1):

Після відповіді [Анатолія](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/4381/9) звернувся, до автора редагування на Вікіпедії:

> [Тут](https://uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%A0%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&type=revision&diff=6542473&oldid=6454239) ви вжили термін обезрозмірнити, а також безрозмірні змінні. Звідки ці терміни. Мені дивно чути префікс обез- зазвичай кажуть зне-. Питання виникло [тут](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/4377/%D0%AF%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-nondimensionalization). --[Igor Yalovecky](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87:Igor_Yalovecky) ([обговорення](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0:Igor_Yalovecky)) 10:06, 21 червня 2018 (UTC)
>
> > Не знаю звідки. Так говорять у моєму середовищі. Проти «**знерозмірити**» не заперечую. *Знерозмірювання можливий варіант обезрозмірювання. **Власне, звучить краще***. На що ви збираєтеся замінити слово безрозмірні, не маю гадки. Розмірні величити це ті. що мають розмірність, безрозмірні - просто числа. --[Дядько Ігор](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87:%D0%94%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%86%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80) ([обговорення](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0:%D0%94%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%86%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80)) 14:26, 21 червня 2018 (UTC)

Цікаве дослідження префіксів **зне-** і **обез-** можна знайти в [Особливості вживання префіків зне- та обез- у дієслівному термінотворенні](http://confesp.fl.kpi.ua/node/1260):

> Більшання продуктивності префікса обез‑ пов’язуємо з мовною політикою Радянського Союзу. Як відомо з термінологічних бюлетенів, основним звинуваченням до термінознавців 20‑х рр. ХХ ст. було відмежовування української мови від російської [2, с. 249–254; 3, с. 219–243; 6, с. 234–249]. Серед іншого у відповідних документах йдеться про надмірне вживання дієслів з префіксами **зне-** для перекладу російських лексем з **обез‑ (обес‑)** [22, с. 156]. Показово, що П. Горецький, який виступив з критикою засад термінотворення 20‑х рр. ХХ ст., не наводить переконливих лінгвістичних фактів на користь сполуки префіксів **обез‑** й радить використовувати відповідний тип термінотворення лише з огляду на його подібність до російської мови, тобто критика мовознавця ґрунтується не на лінгвістичних засадах, а зумовлена позамовними факторами [12, с. 156].

Отже, з префіксом наче розібрались, ще треба вирішити щодо того який варіант правильний:

- Знерозмірювання
- Знерозмірнення